# Convert special characters to HTML character codes

Tags: php, html, regex, content-management-system, special-characters

I'm developing a CMS for a customer and he needs to edit stuff and use special characters such as `ç` and `®`. However, I don't want him to have to enter the character codes like `&reg;`. Does anyone knows a good way to automatically convert those characters using PHP?

Comment: Err. Just make sure your character encoding is consistent (i.e. just use UTF-8 throughout), and you don't need to convert those characters for them to display perfectly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use htmlentities() to do that.

```
php -r 'echo htmlentities("®ç", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"), "\n";'
&reg;&ccedil;
```

To turn entities back to readable text, use html_entity_decode():

```
php -r 'echo html_entity_decode("&reg;&ccedil;", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"), "\n";'
®ç
```

If you're not using unicode, omit the charset name or give the correct charset.

Comment: Fantastic answer that solves a problem I've contended with for a few years.  Worth noting that some of the other answers which mention copy pasting or hard coding the ALT KeyCode version of the symbol will not work when you move your code from operating system to operating system.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to use UTF-8 right from the start.
But you can also automatically convert characters with DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->appendChild(new DOMText('© oui içi » '));
echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

outputs

```
&copy; oui i&ccedil;i &raquo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use unicode, and show him how to copy&paste from character map :-)

Comment: @Alin It's not *that* bad an answer, I'd say -- if the client is already using characters like ç and ®, then using UTF-8, say, for the input, storage and output of the CMS will enable you to do away with the need for the HTML entities. Just like it's doing on this web page, for example, where I just typed in "®", sent it to the site, and the site's displaying it as "®" -- look in the source code for this page, and you won't see an HTML entity there, just the actual, real character.

Comment: @MattGibson One issue is if you use source control and you move your code back and forth between unix-based operating systems and windows operating systems.  I've learned the hard way that ALT key codes don't work the way you want them to across operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

[htmlentities](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.  This takes a string and converts component characters into their HTML entities.  You can specify the encoding of the string to be consistent with the user's input.